# how do I use a request variable into a field value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the response of a request to set a value of my page once it's loaded, but the function that get the value is returning undefined.

```
var get_Token = async () => {
  const token = await getToken();
  return token;
};
const getToken = async () => {
  $.get("example.endpoing.org").success(function(res) {
    return res;
  });
};

var token = get_Token();
$(document).ready(function(token) {
  $("#access_token").val(token);
});
```

Comment: Yeah... Thats not how async functions work. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: `getToken` is not returning anything...

Comment: how do I make it to return the response of this request?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use `async` functions. The correct would be:

```
const getToken = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    $.get("example.endpoing.org").success(resolve);
});

$(document).ready(async () => {
    var token = await getToken(); 
    $("#access_token").val(token); 
});
```